# Python: select function

Tags: python, select, numpy

With this code:

```
import scipy
from scipy import *
x = r_[1:15]  
print x 
a = select([x > 7, x >= 4],[x,x+10])  
print a
```

I get this answer:

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
[ 0  0  0 14 15 16 17  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
```

But why do I have zeros in the beginning and not in the end? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's your `select` function come from?

Comment: `select` isn't a built-in function in python, so you'll have to give more details of the context for anyone to help you. i.e. Where is the `select` function defined? What are the types of `x` and `r_`?

Comment: What is that `select()` function? I can only find this: http://docs.python.org/library/select.html

Comment: I mean the select function from numpy or scipy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be using numpy.

From the [documentation for numpy.select()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

> `numpy.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0)`
>
> ...
>
> *default*: The element inserted in output when all conditions evaluate to `False`.

Since your conditions are `x > 7` and `x >=4`, the output array will have elements from `x+10` when `x >= 4` and from `x` when `x > 7`.  When both the conditions are false, i.e., when `x < 4`, you will get *default*, which is 0.  So you get 3 zeros in the beginning.

You don't get any zeros in the end because at least one of the conditions is true (both are true, in fact).

Comment: I thougt there is only one condition. Sorry, I was blind.